# c#: how to get the object that inherited the passed in object

Tags: c#, oop, object, inheritance

I am making a game/game engine and encountered the following problem: i have a player that has a "checkCollision(Wall w)" method. it takes in a very simple object wall, which has some data and checks the collision with it. this works fine. but now i have this "door" object, which inherited the object "wall". this object is mostly the same but has some extra functionality. now haw can i call functions from this door object? so the door looks like: `class Door : Wall {}`
The function checkCollsion: takes a wall as type in.: `player.checkCollision(Wall w)` the i pass for example `Door d1` in the function: `player.checkCollision(d1)`.
now i can check the collison, and it works fine, but how do i call a function from the door passed in as wall from inside the checkCollision function? ps each object has a tag, and a walls tag  = "wall" and a doors tag = "door".
so i the checkCollision:

```
public void checkCollision(Wall w){
    if(w.tag =="wall"){
        //collision checking
    }else if(w.tag == "door"){
        //collision checking
        //this is a function only "door" has:
        w.SomeMethodOnlyDoorHasAndWallLacks();
    }
}
```

how can i call this function?

thanks in advance,

cody

Comment: you could have multiple overloads which is more oop friendly.

Comment: It's arguable that if you're passing in a `Wall`, it shouldn't try to treat it as a `Door`.  What happens when you create `Window` or `PartitionWall` or ... are you going to hard code different checks for each of those too?

Comment: Coincidentally, Eric Lippert has started a series on a [similar problem](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/).  It might be worth reading as it may keep you from making bad design decisions (which I would argue you are currently doing by switching logic based on the type of object passed in)

Comment: James' answer is worth taking on board. Wall and door should not be linked by inheritance at all, this is a classic example of misuse and you'll cause yourself problems. Inheritance should be used for abstractions and specializations of things that have a clear is-a relationship, not as a convenience tool where no conceptual relationship exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Variant 1:**

```
public void checkCollision(Wall w){
    if(w is Door){
        //collision checking
        //this is a function only "door" has:
        (w as Door).SomeMethodOnlyDoorHasAndWallLacks();
    }else
        // wall
    }
}
```

**Variant 2:**

Define method for collision check in base class:

```
class Wall
{
    public virtual void CheckCollision(some arguments)
    {
        // default collision check code
    }
}

class Door : Wall
{
    public override void CheckCollision(some arguments)
    {
        // overriden collision check code
    }
}
```

Comment: The variant 1: how can you pass DOOR object to function with signature WALL ?

Comment: easy, because Door inherits Wall

Comment: although the other answer may  be better, this is the answer for the question i asked. also, i learned something new here. this is why your answer is correct. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would not inherit door from wall. Create some base object or interface and inherit both wall and door from it:

```
public abstract class EnvironmentObject
{
     // tag

     public bool CheckCollision()
     {
         // collision checking             
     }

     public abstract void Act();
}
```

Now when implementing `Act` in wall object you can leave it empty. In door object you can add some actions. And collision checking will look like

```
var objects = new EnvironmentObject[] { new Wall(), new Door() };

foreach(var obj in objects)
   if (obj.CheckCollision())
       obj.Act();
```